# Replacing dates with SED or AWK (or whatever works) - Linux regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I would like convert:

```
Charlie answered 9 years ago
random text
Kevin answered 4 months ago
```

To this:

```
Charlie answered around March 2006
random text
Kevin answered around November 2014
```

Using the following code:

```
date "+%B %Y" --date="9 years ago"
```

is where I got **March 2006** from.

Should I use a for loop since I will be using instances where there will be 10+ dates that say "answered ______ ago"

Which program is recommended? Sed, awk, any more?

Thank you, I am doing this for a Professor who wants to do research on the accuracy of Yahoo Answers, and I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it in BASH:

```
while read -r line; do
   [[ $line != *answered* ]] && echo "$line" && continue
   date "+${line/answered */answered} around %B %Y" -d "${line#* answered }"
done < file
```

**Output:**

```
Charlie answered around March 2006
random text
Kevin answered around November 2014
```

Comment: @ericramos1990 to be clear, it's not a bad approach but as written it WILL fail given some contents of "random text". Just because it produces the expected output given some specific sample input set you are testing it on does not mean it will always work - you've got to think a bit about what it's doing. Change the second sample input line to `random answered text` and see what happens. Now try indenting the random text.

Comment: I modified it to:  `[[ $line != *answered*ago ]]`   Now it only changes lines that have the words "answered" and "ago". Now the chance of error is still there, but it is much smaller since the random text is more rare to have both words.

Comment: Right, now it'll just strip off any indentation or trailing blanks. You need `while IFS= read -r line; do` to solve that. The crux of the issue is that the UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools, not a tool to manipulate text, and so it's cumbersome and inefficient to try to do that in shell without unexpected side-effects. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. Again, though, it's not a huge deal in this case, you just should be aware of the caveats.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk         
/answered/ && match($0,/[0-9]+[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+ago/) {
    cmd = "date \"+%B %Y\" --date=\"" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) "\""
    if ( (cmd | getline date) > 0 ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) "around " date
    }
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Charlie answered around March 2006
random text
Kevin answered around November 2014
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for your answer.Will it work on Bash?

Comment: Of course, it'll work on any OS in any shell. It's awk, it's not tied to any shell or OS as long as the `date` command present supports the given constructs.

Comment: I do understand your feedback on anubhava's approach with "random answered text" failing since it has the word "answered"
However, I am much more familiar with running anubhava's approach. How do I run your code properly?

Comment: Precisely as shown in the answer. Is there something about it that isn't clear?

Comment: Got it Ed, I was not aware that I had to create the tst.awk file myself, now I understand the cat tst.awk. Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more  `awk`

```
awk -F"answered " 'NF>1{"date \"+%B %Y\" --date=\""$2"\"" | getline t;$2=FS "around "t}1' file
Charlie  answered around March 2006
random text
Kevin  answered around November 2014
```